# How to replace an alphabetic character in a string with null in Java?

Tags: java

I need to take a string that contains a mix of characters and numbers and a delimiter, scan it for anything not a number or a decimal point or the ; delimiter, then it would be nulled out. Here's an example:

```js
; Pages / sec ; 0 . 1 7 ; 0 ; 0 . 1 3 ; 0 . 0 5 ; 0 . 1 ; 0 . 1 3 ; 0 . 2 5 ; 0 . 0 3 ; 0 . 0 3 ; 0 . 1 ;
```

This string would become:

```java
;0.17;0;0.13;0.05;0.1;0.13;0.25;0.03;0.03;0.1;
```

Basically the only thing left in the string is the ";" delimiter and any integers or floating point numbers in between the delimiter. Anything a character or a space is removed.

```java
String stringToScan = "; Pages / sec ; 0 . 1 7 ; 0 ; 0 . 1 3 ; 0 . 0 5 ; 0 . 1 ; 0 . 1 3 ; 0 . 2 5 ; 0 . 0 3 ; 0 . 0 3 ; 0 . 1 ;" 
String resultingString = stringToScan.replace(?, '')
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you're expected to use a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to solve your assignment.

Comment: Your example output contradicts with your requirement: *"scan it for anything not a number or a decimal point"*, since `;` is also neither a number or a decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String src = "; Pages / sec ; 0 . 1 7 ; 0 ; 0 . 1 3 ; 0 . 0 5 ; 0 . 1 ; 0 . 1 3 ; 0 . 2 5 ; 0 . 0 3 ; 0 . 0 3 ; 0 . 1 ; ";
System.out.println(src.replaceAll("[^0-9\\.;]", "").replaceAll(";+", ";"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As Giovani Vercauteren already stated, you need a regular expression.
Anything not being a digit, point or semicolon should be removed.
So:

```
String resultingString = stringToScan.replaceAll("[^0-9\\.\\;]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be able to detect numeric values, so you will need a regular expression for that.

Next, you need to remove all white-space.

Finally, you just split the string, filter out the bad criteria and join the results together.

Not sure if the leading and ending semi-colons are really needed, but you can just prepend/append them to the result.

```java
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Replacer {
    private static final Pattern NUMERIC_ONLY = Pattern.compile("^[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$");

    private static Predicate<String> isValid = new Predicate<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String str) {
            return str != null && !str.isEmpty() && NUMERIC_ONLY.matcher(str).matches();
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "; Pages / sec ; 0 . 1 7 ; 0 ; 0 . 1 3 ; 0 . 0 5 ; 0 . 1 ; 0 . 1 3 ; 0 . 2 5 ; 0 . 0 3 ; 0 . 0 3 ; 0 . 1 ;";

        System.out.println(formatAndRemoveNonNumeric(str, ";"));
    }

    public static String formatAndRemoveNonNumeric(String str, String delim) {
        return Stream.of(str.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split(delim)).filter(isValid).collect(Collectors.joining(delim));
    }
}
```

**Result:** `0.17;0;0.13;0.05;0.1;0.13;0.25;0.03;0.03;0.1`

Answer (score 0):

I have written a ***regular expression*** for it.

Below is the solution for your requirement

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringToScan = "; Pages / sec ; 0 . 1 7 ; 0 ; 0 . 1 3 ; 0 . 0 5 ; 0 . 1 ; 0 . 1 3 ; 0 . 2 5 ; 0 . 0 3 ; 0 . 0 3 ; 0 . 1 ;"; 
        String result = stringToScan.replaceAll("[^0-9\\.\\;]", "");

        System.out.println(result);
}
```

I hope this will help Thanks...